# How to achieve this using Lambda

Tags: sql, database, linq, entity-framework

I've got problem with writing a Lambda expression,
Here's my situation. I've got a tablenamed FromStruct.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[formStruct](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fieldName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [fieldValue] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,

GO
```

An example table would be like:

```
id | Name | Value
1  | John | 87
2  | James| 35
3  | Chris| 22
```

And I've got an array of strings like:

```
string[] names ={"John","James","Joe"}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to build three different Lambda expressions for the following tasks:
1- A lambda expression to return all the records which their field name **IS NOT** in the array.
It should result in `"Chris | 52"`, because Chris is not in the names array.

2- A lambda expression to return all the records which their field name IS in the names array.
It should result in `"John | 87" and "James | 35"` .

3- A lambda expression to Delete all the records which their field name **IS in** the names array. It should result in `"John | 87" and "James | 35"` being removed from the table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks more like a table to me :) Can you share your C# code attempt too please? And tag with language, e.g. C#?

Comment: @StuartLC, Yes, It's actually a table, my bad, Sorry. I didn't write any code for this right now mainly because I couldn't make the needed lambda expressions. If I could make the expressions the rest is a piece of cake.

Comment: Take a look at [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: You don't delete records by a lambda expression, 2 and 3 are identical.

Comment: @StuartLC The field I need to select is inside the names array, your hint code results in all field names getting selected, which is different from my need. I need to select all the records which their field name is inside the names array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an example of what you will need. Feel free to post it in test application and then make necessary changes for your application:

```
void Main(){
List<Test> test = new List<Test>();
test.Add(new Test{ID=1,Name="John",Value=87});
test.Add(new Test{ID=2,Name="James",Value=35});
test.Add(new Test{ID=3,Name="Chris",Value=52});

string[] names ={"John","James","Joe"};

var notContains  = test.Where (t =>!names.Contains(t.Name) );


var contains = test.Where (t => names.Contains(t.Name));


 var delete = test.RemoveAll(t=>names.Contains(t.Name));

}

   public  class Test{

  public int ID{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public int Value {get;set;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below queries, this is just logic, do some modification if required.

//create database entity as dbEntities

//result 1 to get data which is not having name in array

```
var result1 =(from u in dbEntities.formStruct.AsEnumerable()
        where !names.Any(s => s == u.fieldName)
         select u
         ).ToList();
```

//result 2 to get data which having names in array

```
var result2 =(from u in dbEntities.formStruct.AsEnumerable()
        where names.Any(s => s == u.fieldName)
         select u
         ).ToList();
```

//here you will get result of  List object. From this you can print text which you required.

```
var result = formStruct.Where(w => names.Contains(w)).ToList();
formStruct.RemoveAll(u => names.Contains(u.fieldName));
```

//after removing records you can print the required text.

Please share your feedback on the same.